# Bulkifying Apex code issue from a non coder, updating related record based on soql query in apex

Tags: apex

I have some proof of concept code but I know that in a production environment it would quickly run into governor limits issues.

In order tho minimize user licence cost there is a use case where certain objects like cases when created and edited should create then maintain a sort of clone record (not every field or all functionality). The clone record in turn can pass data back to the case.

Based on the attached code with comments I am looking for suggestion of what the most efficient code is to do this task. The code I have runs and works but is not pretty. All suggestions and comments appreciated.

```
trigger Casemaintrigger on Case (after insert,before update) {
    // poof of concept trigger

    // Check what type of triggerfired
    if(trigger.isinsert){
        // if it is an insert trigger create a new Test_custom_object record for each new case

        Test_custom_object__c tcos = new Test_custom_object__c();
        for (case c : Trigger.new){
            tcos.Case_name__c = c.CaseNumber;   
            tcos.Case_issue__c = c.Description;
            // Note Case id is written to a read only field but allows for relationship to case to be maintained without the need for a lookup / master detail 
            // This is being done so salient case information in theory can be made available to force.com app only licence types
            tcos.Caseid__c =c.Id;

        }
        insert tcos;
        // this insert should be ok one DML consumed
    }
    if(trigger.isupdate)  {
        // If trigger is update then we need to get the matching Test_custom_object records and edit them
        // create a set of just the Case id's....not sure if this is most efficient approach
        set <string> idfromcase = new set<string>();
        For (case ca :trigger.new){
            idfromcase.add(ca.Id);
        }
        //create a list of all the matching Test_custom_object records......one querry consumed
        list<Test_custom_object__c> tco = [select id,Caseid__c,Case_issue__c,Case_name__c From Test_custom_object__c where Caseid__c IN : idfromcase ];
        //loop through all the cases modified
        For(case cas : trigger.new){
            //loop through the matching Test_custom_object record's
            for(Test_custom_object__c i : tco){
               // when the id's match overwrite the choosen fields so data is consistent 
                if(i.Caseid__c==cas.Id){
                    i.Case_issue__c = cas.Description;
                    i.Case_name__c = cas.subject;
                }
                //update the record!! okay i can't move "i" or the variable is out of context but leaving the update call here  will burn DML calls 
                // Question is how to achiev the goal of this code in the most efficient way
                update i;
                }

            }
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update to your code with some improvements. Please look through the comments so you can learn some more about where you would need to bulkify and where we can use a map for more effective code. I also added in some of Bethany's ideas with the try catch and bulkifying the update call.

---

```
trigger Casemaintrigger on Case (after insert,before update) {
    // poof of concept trigger

    // Check what type of triggerfired
    if(trigger.isinsert){

        // Need to create a list for insert in the event multiple cases are inserted or updated at once: think apis like dataloader
        List<Test_custom_object__c> tcosForInsert = new List<Test_custom_object__c>();
        for (case c : Trigger.new){
            // if it is an insert trigger create a new Test_custom_object record for each new case
            Test_custom_object__c tcos = new Test_custom_object__c();
            tcos.Case_name__c = c.CaseNumber;   
            tcos.Case_issue__c = c.Description;
            // Note Case id is written to a read only field but allows for relationship to case to be maintained without the need for a lookup / master detail 
            // This is being done so salient case information in theory can be made available to force.com app only licence types
            tcos.Caseid__c =c.Id;
            tcosForInsert.add(tcos);
        }
        // see if work needs to be done
        if(tcosForInsert.size() > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bulk insert
                insert tcosForInsert;
            }
            catch(DMLException e)
            {
                // error handling goes here
            }
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isupdate)  {
        // removed loop altogether as you can use trigger.newmap()

        List<Test_custom_object__c> tcos = [select id,Caseid__c,Case_issue__c,Case_name__c From Test_custom_object__c where Caseid__c IN : trigger.newmap.keyset()];

        //Create a map of case id to tcos - will allow for tighter loop here and then map get later
        Map<Id, Test_custom_object__c> tcoMap = new Map<Id, Test_custom_object__c>();
        for(Test_custom_object__c tco : tcos)
        {
            tcoMap.put(tco.Caseid__c, tco);
        }
        //Create list for updating clone object
        List<Test_custom_object__c> tcoForUpdate = new List<Test_custom_object__c>();

        For(case cas : trigger.new){
            // Check if clone record already exists
            if(tcoMap.containsKey(cas.Caseid__c))
            {
                // Update cloned record
                Test_custom_object__c existingTCO = tcoMap.get(cas.Caseid__c);
                existingTCO.Case_issue__c = cas.Description;
                existingTCO.Case_name__c = cas.subject;
                tcoForUpdate.add(existingTCO);
            }
            else
            {
                // you may want to consider what should happen if the record is not found (possibility to refactor the initial trigger.isinsert to another method and pass a list of what is caught here)
            }
        }
        //Check if we need to update anything
        if(tcoForUpdate.size() > 0)
        {
            try 
            {
                update tcoForUpdate;    
            }
            catch (DMLException e) 
            {
                //manage exception here
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for all your edits and for showing how to properly use a map for the second part of the trigger.  I am assuming  the "i" references should actually be "existingTCO" if not then i am confused on you update clone record section. As a side note this was only to prove a concept and while I don't code When i use developers I like to see single triggers that then run to a trigger factory or some other appropriate pattern that handles execution order and flow logic. In this Proof of concept the clone object can also write back to case so recursion need preventing. Many thanks David

Comment: Thanks for the catch, updated the code to reflect i = existingTCO .

Answer (score 3):

You should not do a dml statement in a for loop - it will update 1 record at a time until it hits the governor of 150 per execution.

Instead, you could add your records to a list inside the for loop, and update your list outside of the for loop. See below:

```
List<Test_Custom_Object__c> updateList = new List<Test_Custom_Object__c>();

for(Test_custom_object__c i : tco)
{
    if(i.Caseid__c==cas.Id)
    {
        i.Case_issue__c = cas.Description;
        i.Case_name__c = cas.subject;
        updateList.add(i);
    }
}

Update updateList;
```

You should also consider partial processing or a try/catch block based on how you want to do error handling.

Comment: Bethany.    Thanks for your comments. One of my reasons for posting the code for improvement is I knew that I had a DML inside a for Loop. To move it outside of the for loop I also realized that I could do it with yet another list. Not being a familiar with coding I wondered if I was even approaching the problem in right way. It seemed I was creating a awful lot of variables. Thanks for you suggestions. and confirmation i was at least in the right direction